# Many Dynamodb Partitions or more data stored in a partition?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In one of my tables I store data that is used to display statistics.
Let's say that the below example is somehow similar to the data saved in my table:

Partition Key: BUSINESS#<business_id>#DATE#2023-11-17
Sort Key: PRODUCT#<product_id>
Attributes: Quantity, ....

My project will have many businesses and for each of them will create for every day a new partition that holds the data for every product that has been sold.

Is this approach good for the long run, or it would be better to store all the data into a singe partition for every business? I don't know how good practice are neither one of these approaches.

(or should I make a new partition for every business by month date, not by day date?)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should not use date in your partition key. You've not provided your read access patterns so it's impossible to tell your use case. But your current data model you cannot get all information for a business in a single request, you'd have to make a request for each day. So for one months data, that's approx 30 requests.

Having a partition key as just Business would be better, so long as it does not cause a hot key for you. A hot key is caused when a given Business consumes more than 1000 WCU or 3000 RCU per second.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

When I want to get all information for a business in a single request I'm using a GSI.

Comment: What do you use your base table for?

Comment: To store data for every business that can be used to get statistics for a period of time by some filters like "type" or "category".

Comment: Your base table is not set up to do that efficiently, so your current schema is forcing you to have an index which is not required. Having a business as Partition key saves you having an index and ultimately reduces your cost while also providing you greater query flexibility.

Comment: Thank you! I will take in consideration your suggestions and make some changes to the table schema.